# Why this code prints the correct results of sorting 3 integers, however it shouldn't due to integer overflow?

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

Consider the following code which prints the ascending order of `3` integers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a, b, c;
  cin >> a >> b >> c;
  int mn = a, mx = a;
  if (b > mx)
    mx = b;
  if (c > mx)
    mx = c;
  if (b < mn)
    mn = b;
  if (c < mn)
    mn = c;
    
  int mid = (a + b + c) - (mn + mx);
  
  cout << mn << " " << mid << " " << mx << "\n";
}
```

Let's assume -10^9 <= a, b, c <= 10^9. So there's no overflow when reading them.

The expression `(a + b + c)` should cause overflow when `(a + b + c)` > `INT_MAX`, however the `mid` variable print correct results. I tried to print "a + b + c" in a separate line, it printed some negative value (clearly it's an overflow). My question is: Does the compiler make optimization when the result of expression fits in integer data type?

Comment: `INT_MAX +1` may get `INT_MIN`, and `INT_MIN - 1` may get `INT_MAX`, so `INT_MAX + 1 - 1` may get `INT_MAX` which is a "correct" result, but noticed that signed int overflow is ub so it may get any value

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) is *undefined* - anything can happen - including the program appearing to work. It is still UB though and as such, the program is invalid and you have no guarantees about what it will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that a signed integer overflow can occur here, which is undefined behavior. But undefined behavior means that "anything can happen".

And here "anything can happen" means "2's complement arithmetic". Which works out the correct answer.

> Does the compiler make optimization when the result of expression fits
> in integer data type?

No special optimizations are needed. The compiled code simply uses integer addition and subtraction that gets carried out using the rules for 2's complement arithmetic. The underlying hardware does not generate an exception for signed integer overflow, the addition simply wraps around, using 2's complement arithmetic.

The addition wraps around, and the subtraction wraps back to where it came from. Everyone lives happily ever after.